# How can I determine the lowest flash player version my swf can be published for?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a project that is complete. How can I determine the lowest flash player version I can publish this project for?

I am using Flash Builder 4.7.

Also I am using:
Starling
Feathers
Dragon Bones
Citrus
Nape

Answer (score 0):

You should look on the Starling, Feathers UI etc sites for the minimum Flash Player version that they require for the version that you are using and then take the highest one.